# NAS not discovered in Windows 7 Network

Tags: windows-7, nas

I have a Synology NAS which isn't discovered when I go to Network on my company laptop at home, but it is on our own private laptop. I have turned on network discovery.
Also if I type in `\\servername` in the address field it asks for username/password.
It says:

> The system detected a possible attempt to compromise security. Please ensure that you can contact the server that authenticated you.

I can write any user name and it connects fine. I don't need to write a password. On the private laptop it doesn't ask for user name/password but just connects. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The device you are using should have a built in webpage (like configuring your router from the normal default of 192.168.1.1) when you connect to it with your personal laptop, go to network devices, click on properties and jot down the local IP address for the device probably something like 192.168.1.4. Open the browser of your choice on your company laptop and enter the address you jotted down - that should bring you to the main configuration page and data access for your NAS.

From there you should be able to add access to individual devices such as your company laptop. If not, access the page on your personal laptop and then add your company laptop to the list of accepted users.

As per the security prompt you are receiving - it may be caused by a security software policy your company laptop has installed.

Comment: I have no problem connecting, just with the network discovery (and the security prompt as a minor annoyances)